# Xamarin forms: select and pick multiple document files(doc, pdf, xlx, etc...) at once Cross-Platform

Tags: file, xamarin, xamarin.forms, document, filepicker

I want to select and pick **only multiple document files**(such as: **doc, pdf, xlx, txt,** etc...) at once in the file picker dialogue.

How to do that?

I have seen `pt.Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker` and `Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker` plugins but **unable to fulfill my requirement.**

Have any idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through all of the chooses that you selected;

```
foreach (var element in MyListOfFiles.Where(f => f.IsSelected)) { /* do download with HttpClient or something here */ }
```